# Confusing notation related to functions

Tags: notation

The notation given is:

$$g(x)= \min\lbrace f(t): -3\leq t \leq x, -3\leq x \leq0\rbrace$$

What does this even mean? Is this just another way of saying that $t\in[0,3]$ ?

Comment: I agree that this notation is indeed confusing. Where do you find this? Is it form some book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that $g(x) $ is the smallest value of $f(t)$ where $t \in [-3, x] $ and that $x \in [-3, 0]$. In essence, the value that $t$ can take is dependent on the value of $x$ as well.

Maybe, you could also shed light on where you encountered the above function.

Comment: It was actually a whole question and there was a similar notation with $max$ instead of $min$.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a mistake. Probably what is meant is
$$g(x)= \min\lbrace f(t): -3\leq t \leq x\rbrace, -3\leq x \leq0$$

That means, for each $x$ you look at the minimum value of $f$ in the region $-3\leq t \leq x$.

The domain for $g$ is $[-3,0]$.